# Rendering New Lines in TextViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to render newlines in a textview. I'm giving the textview text a value having new lines in it, but it's not  working.

My Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var postTextTextViewOutlet : UITextView!

let postDescription = "Testing \nNew\nLine\nIssue\n...\n...."

func configureUI() { 
    self.postTextTextViewOutlet.attributedText = postDescription.html2AttributedString        
}

extension String { 
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8),
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the newlines are not being shown when displayed:

[image]

please can anyone help, and thank you

Comment: Try it with tag `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
self.postTextTextViewOutlet.text = postDescription
```

Comment: Try This

let firstString = "Hello"

let secondString = "Senorita"

textview.text = firstString + "\n" + "secondString"